# Updating list in Python dictionaries depending on dictionary's key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I created a dictionary that is initialized automatically according to the number of devices available as follow:

```
def _sensors_discovery(self,con, req):

    if self.sensors[0] in con.labels:
        device = con.resourceName
        if device not in self.device_list:  # get all the devices
            self.device_list.append(device)
            self.dictLists = dict((key, []) for key in self.device_list)
```

A you may noticed I initialized for each device or "key" an empty list as value.After this i want to append for each list different items therefore i created this functions that uses `self.dictLists` and tried to append items for the corresponding device as follow:

```
        for k, v in self.dictLists.iteritems():
            if k in item: # the item contain already the device name therefore i check here if the device name is in the item and then i append it to the list of the corresponding device
                    v.append(items)
        print self.dictLists
```

it works but not as expected! because what happen is that as soon as a new items that belong to different device appears, the previous device items are deleted and only the new device list is fulfilled. Maybe the output of `print self.dictLists` helps to understand the problem.

```
{u'device1': [u'item1']}
{device1': [u'item1', u'item2']}
{device1': [u'item1', u'item2', u'item3']}
```

then this happen when a new device appears:

```
 {u'device2': [u'item1_d2], u'device1': []}
 {u'device2': [u'item1_d2, u'item2_d2'], u'device1': []}
    ...
```

i tried with `self.dictLists.setdefault(k, []).append(item)` but it works the same way as well.
Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The code you mentioned here should work fine. The issue is somewhere else in the code which you have not shared.

Comment: You mean that it can be related to the items or something ? because the items i got them automatically form another functions and in each one i have the device name that it belong to.

Comment: As per what my senses say, you are re-calling the part which initializes your dict `self.dictLists`. But I may be wrong, as I haven't seen the code, and the order in which these are called.

Comment: I can share both functions to check the order but its from a kinda complicated project it wont be easy to understand i believe

Comment: If code looks complicated, then it was not properly structured at the first place :) Share your code at the end of question, someone might be able to caught your issue.

Comment: As per my thumb rule, a function should never exceed 10 lines. If it does, there is always a scope to divide it into smaller functions ;)

Comment: plz check the first function i added it. I think the problem is located there because when the device_list and the `self.dictLists` are created at the same time and at the same time the other function tries to get items for the device when a new device is added to the list, the `self.dictLists` is created form scratch therefore everything is deleted

Comment: The issue is same as what my senses told me earlier (my erlier comment). In  `_sensors_discovery()` function, you are re-initializing the `self.dictLists` everytime you make an entry to `self.device_list`

Comment: thats exactly the problem ! now I m trying to fix it using while instead of if to check if the device is in the `device_list` or not. Do you think that would help?

Comment: My understanding is that you want to add `device` as key to existing dict. Just simply do `self.dictLists.setdefault(device, [])`. It will add empty list as value to the `dict` if `device` does not exists as key to it

Comment: Thnk you  !!! it works! just copy past your comment in answer so i can accept it to get your point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function:

```
def _sensors_discovery(self,con, req):
    if self.sensors[0] in con.labels:
        device = con.resourceName
        if device not in self.device_list:  # get all the devices
            self.device_list.append(device)
            self.dictLists = dict((key, []) for key in self.device_list)  
            # ^ ^ ^ Here you are re-initializing the dict
```

Instead, you need to just add the value of `device` to `self.dictLists` as `key` with default value as `[]`. For that use `dict.setdefault()` as:

```
self.dictLists.setdefault(device, [])
```